# Firebase on listener with react native

Tags: javascript, android, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

So I'm trying to attach a .on listener, like so

```
firebase.database().ref('Users').child('AhvRcIT2anTaucSDoOgt2MLNxgZ2').on('value', snap => {
    const user = snap.val();
    alert(true);
}).catch(e => alert(e))
```

The problem is, I get an error saying

> Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info. (Saw setTimeout with duration 398331ms)

which I guess makes sense. The only solutions I could find were to just hide the warning, which sounds like a bad idea. Especially that my app started freezing after a while when I added this listener.

I know there is `react-native-firebase` available, but I've read all it does, is just hide the warning, not really solving the problem.

How can this problem be solved though? Or does it just have to be like this on Android?

Entire home class

```
export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
    static navigationOptions = {
        header: null,
    };

    componentWillMount() {
        (async () => {
            await firebase.auth().signInAndRetrieveDataWithEmailAndPassword('loigin', 'pass');
            const val = await firebase.database().ref('Users').child('AhvRcIT2anTaucSDoOgt2MLNxgZ2').once('value').then(r => r.val()).catch(e => alert(e));
            alert(val);
        })();
    }


    render() {
        // firebase.database().ref('Users').child('AhvRcIT2anTaucSDoOgt2MLNxgZ2').on('value', snap => {
        //     const user = snap.val();
        //     alert(true);
        // }).catch(e => alert(e))
        alert(false)
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView style={styles.container} contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>
                    <View style={styles.welcomeContainer}>
                        <Image
                            source={
                                __DEV__
                                    ? require('../assets/images/robot-dev.png')
                                    : require('../assets/images/robot-prod.png')
                            }
                            style={styles.welcomeImage}
                        />
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.getStartedContainer}>
                        {this._maybeRenderDevelopmentModeWarning()}

                        <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>Get started by opening</Text>

                        <View style={[styles.codeHighlightContainer, styles.homeScreenFilename]}>
                            <MonoText style={styles.codeHighlightText}>screens/HomeScreen.js</MonoText>
                        </View>

                        <Text style={styles.getStartedText}>
                            Change this text and your app will automatically reload.
                        </Text>
                    </View>

                    <View style={styles.helpContainer}>
                        <TouchableOpacity onPress={this._handleHelpPress} style={styles.helpLink}>
                            <Text style={styles.helpLinkText}>Help, it didn’t automatically reload!</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
                </ScrollView>

                <View style={styles.tabBarInfoContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.tabBarInfoText}>This is a tab bar. You can edit it in:</Text>

                    <View style={[styles.codeHighlightContainer, styles.navigationFilename]}>
                        <MonoText style={styles.codeHighlightText}>navigation/MainTabNavigator.js</MonoText>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

    _maybeRenderDevelopmentModeWarning() {
        if (__DEV__) {
            const learnMoreButton = (
                <Text onPress={this._handleLearnMorePress} style={styles.helpLinkText}>
                    Learn more
                </Text>
            );

            return (
                <Text style={styles.developmentModeText}>
                    Development mode is enabled, your app will be slower but you can use useful development
                    tools. {learnMoreButton}
                </Text>
            );
        } else {
            return (
                <Text style={styles.developmentModeText}>
                    You are not in development mode, your app will run at full speed.
                </Text>
            );
        }
    }

    _handleLearnMorePress = () => {
        WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync('https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/development-mode');
    };

    _handleHelpPress = () => {
        WebBrowser.openBrowserAsync(
            'https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/up-and-running.html#can-t-see-your-changes'
        );
    };
}
```

Comment: Can you please share more code.

Comment: I added the whole component

Answer (score 0):

You can try below for your **componentWillMount**

```
 componentWillMount() {
            firebase
            .auth()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword('loigin', 'pass')
            .then(() => {

                firebase.database()
                    .ref('Users')
                    .child('AhvRcIT2anTaucSDoOgt2MLNxgZ2').on('value', function (snapshot) {
                        alert(snapshot.val())
                    })
                    .catch(e => alert(e));

            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(error.message)
            })
}
```

Comment: Well ok, but I need the app to listen to changes in the database. `Once` just takes the current state of the database node.

Comment: I updated my answer. You can use on instead of once.

Comment: How is that different from the example I gave? It just uses then instead of await. Or am I missing something? + the warning persists